# Excel formula confusion

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Try to use this formula but the ISNA part is not working. Can someone please tell me if I am doing something wrong?

```
=IF(OR(D18<3,ISNA(D18)),"None (Attendee did not submit minimum required number of 3 polling questions)",IF(B18="Presenter",(C18/50)*3,C18/50))
```

Comment: Problem would be that if `D18` holds an `#N/A` error, the first component of the `OR` construct would yield an error on itself and despite the second part returning `TRUE` this would break the formula right there. Use `IFERROR` in `D18` and scratch the `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

when D18 is err (#N/A, #name?, #DIV0!....), ISNA(D18) will shows "True", however, D18<3 will tell you #N/A, or(D18<3,ISNA(D18)) will shows #N/A

```
=IFERROR(IF(D18<3,"None (Attendee did not submit minimum required number of 3 polling questions)",IF(B18="Presenter",(C18/50)*3,C18/50)),"None")
```